# How do modify a class so that it has only a single member function with all arguments defaulted?

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to programming (in general) and C++ (in particular) and currently learning classes and objects.

I've defined the following as an exercise:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:

    void setNum_1(int);
    void setNum_2(int);
    void setNum_3(int);
    void setNum_4(int);

    double getNum_1();
    double getNum_2(int num_1);
    double getNum_3(int num_1, int num_2);
    double getNum_4(int num_1, int num_2, int num_3);

private:
    int num_1;
    int num_2;
    int num_3;
    int num_4;
};

int main()
{
    X testObject;

    int lNum_1 = 0;
    int lNum_2 = 0;
    int lNum_3 = 0;
    int lNum_4 = 0;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_1;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_2;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_3;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_4;

    testObject.setNum_1(lNum_1);
    testObject.setNum_2(lNum_2);
    testObject.setNum_3(lNum_3);
    testObject.setNum_4(lNum_4);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The 1st number returned is: " << testObject.getNum_1() << endl;
    cout << "The 2nd number returned is: " << testObject.getNum_2(lNum_1) << endl;
    cout << "The 3rd number returned is: " << testObject.getNum_3(lNum_1, lNum_2) << endl;
    cout << "The 4th number returned is: " << testObject.getNum_4(lNum_1, lNum_2, lNum_3) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void X::setNum_1(int n_1)
{
    num_1 = n_1;
}

void X::setNum_2(int n_2)
{
    num_2 = n_2;
}

void X::setNum_3(int n_3)
{
    num_3 = n_3;
}

void X::setNum_4(int n_4)
{
    num_4 = n_4;
}

double X::getNum_1()
{
    return sqrt(num_1);
}

double X::getNum_2(int num_1)
{
    return pow(num_2,3);
}

double X::getNum_3(int num_1, int num_2)
{
    return num_1 * num_2;
}

double X::getNum_4(int num_1, int num_2, int num_3)
{
    return (num_1 + num_2) / num_3;
}
```

Can anyone offer some guidance on how to modify this class so that it has only one member function with all of the arguments defaulted?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. All of your `getNum_` functions do very different operations. `getNum_2` doesn't even use its argument. And the `setNum_` and `getNum_` functions are completely different. How are you expecting this to resolve to a single function with default arguments?

Comment: Also, why do you pass `num_1`, `num_2`, and `num_3` as arguments to the `getNum_` functions instead of using the members `num_1`, `num_2`, `num_3`, and `num_4`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse there are MANY ways to do this and most of them will be more elegant than what I have done here. But this should give you some ideas.

a. You should use the variables defined in the class 
b. If you need to perform certain conditional operations in a function, use a switch case or an if statement. And decide the operation based on a parameter passed.

Again, many ways to make this more elegant, but this should get you started and thinking.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:

    void setNums(int, int, int, int);
    double performOp(int);

private:
    int num_1;
    int num_2;
    int num_3;
    int num_4;
};

int main()
{
    X testObject;

    int lNum_1 = 0;
    int lNum_2 = 0;
    int lNum_3 = 0;
    int lNum_4 = 0;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_1;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_2;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_3;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> lNum_4;

    testObject.setNums(lNum_1,lNum_2,lNum_3,lNum_4);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The 1st number returned is: " << testObject.performOp(1) << endl;
    cout << "The 2nd number returned is: " << testObject.performOp(2) << endl;
    cout << "The 3rd number returned is: " << testObject.performOp(3) << endl;
    cout << "The 4th number returned is: " << testObject.performOp(4) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

void X::setNums(int n_1, int n_2, int n_3, int n_4)
{
    num_1 = n_1;
    num_2 = n_2;
    num_3 = n_3;
    num_4 = n_4;
}

double X::performOp(int n)
{
    if(n == 1) return sqrt(num_1);
    if(n == 2) return pow(num_2,3);
    if(n == 3) return num_1 * num_2;
    if(n == 4) return (num_1 + num_2) / num_3;
}
```

Comment: @ remudada - this is very helpful.  Thank you.  It was exactly what I needed to see how I can extend the idea.